# Paginate in relationship and order by

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pagination, php-7

I have List. List has many posts.

I want to get all post of some lists, sort posts and paginate it.

I try this:

```
$list = List::whereId('1')->firstOrFail();
$posts = $feed->posts()->orderBy('id')->paginate(Request::input('per_page'))->appends(Request::input());

return compact('list','posts');
```

Now I can get List and paginate posts, but ordeBy doesn't work?
How order it? Or any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
$posts= Post::orderBy('id','desc');
```

Answer (score 0):

It works and sorts by `ASC` by default. If you want to reverse it, use `DESC`:

```
->orderBy('id', 'desc')
```

Or:

```
->latest('id')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
->orderBy('id','asc') for Ascending

->orderBy('id','desc') for Decending
```